# Emulator page Orientation is not working

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I have these properties in XAML page

```
SupportedOrientations="PortraitOrLandscape" Orientation="Portrait"
```

But when i changed the Orientation to Landscape its not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your key board is enabled, the Orientation will not work in Emulators.
Try to disable the key board support using "Page Down" key in the key board.
Hope this will help you.